# Phonegap, check if an app got push notification

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

Is it possible for a Phonegap app to check if another app (e.g Whatsapp, Facebook) got a push notification and access the notification?

Answer (score 0):

The real question is : if is even possible with any operating system.

I think not cause this can make some privacy trouble. If you want to access to facebook or other service data's, use there API.

Relatively the same question was posted a week ago that asked if is possible to check permission of other apps from a cordova based apps. The answers was no, so i thinks you'r are on the same case.